# Let $p(x)$ be odd degree polynomial ,$g$ be a bounded real valued continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p(x)$ be  odd degree polynomial in one variable with real co-efficient, $g$ be a bounded real valued continuous function,  we need to show $\exists x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p(x_0)=g(x_0)$

what I did: take $h(x)=p(x)-g(x)$ it is also an odd degree polynomial hence must have a real root, so we are done. am i right? thank you.

Comment: $h(x)$ in fact, cannot be a polynomial unless $g(x)$ is a constant polynomial. As an example, consider $g(x)=\arctan(x)$. It's continuous, real-valued, and bounded. But $h(x)$ is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You have the right general idea, but your $h(x)$ is not necessarily a polynomial. What you can show, however, is that either

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to-\infty}h(x)=-\infty$$

or

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=-\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to-\infty}h(x)=\infty\;,$$

depending on the sign of the leading coefficient of $f$. Now apply the intermediate value theorem to $h$.

Comment: where we are using the fact that $g$ is bounded real valued continuos function?

Comment: @Panu: Continuity is need to make $h$ continuous, so that you can use the intermediate value theorem. Boundedness is needed to make $h$ unbounded in both directions in the same way that $p$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking brians Hint: $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}h(x)=+\infty$ as $g$ is bounded and for the same reason $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}h(x)=-\infty$ as $p$ is of odd degree, now by IVT, there exist $x_0$ $h(x_0)=0$